# Need assistance with an issue due to async nature of Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am having trouble figuring out how to accomplish what I am trying given the asynchronous nature of Node. On a conceptual level I want to do this:

1. Use the Twitter API to run a search
2. Iterate over the resulting tweets to run a sentiment check using 
   alchemylab's api - each tweet with its associated sentiment info
   is pushed onto an array
3. Render the page which can then loop through the array displaying
   the tweets and sentiment info

Here is the code I have:

```js
    client.get('search/tweets', {q: 'node.js'}, function(error, tweets, response)
    {
        for (var i=0; i<tweets.statuses.length; i++){
           var ttext = tweets.statuses[i].text;
           var tsrc = tweets.statuses[i].source;
           var lang = '';
           var sentiment = '';
           var score = '';

           var tweet = {
                         text: tweets.statuses[i].text,
                         source: tweets.statuses[i].source
                       };
          
           alchemyapi.sentiment("text", ttext, {}, function(response) {
 
              if (response.status == 'OK' ){
                tweet.lang = response.language;
                tweet.sentiment = response['docSentiment'].type;
                tweet.score = response['docSentiment'].score;
                console.log("pushing: " + util.inspect(tweet) );
                tweet_data.push( tweet );
              }

           });

        }

        

        res.render('twitter', {
            myText: myText,
        });
    });
```

What's happening is the page is being rendered before any of the alchemyapi calls have completed. I am fairly new to thinking in
async terms and haven't wrapped my head fully around it yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Andy

Edit -

I am trying to implement the deferred approach using Promises and not having much luck.. I have parseTweet defined now as a function as you suggested, if the response is 'OK' it calls resolve(tweet) - not really sure if this is doing anything. My for() loop now looks like this:

```js
            promises.push(parseTweet(tweets.statuses[i]));

            Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
                console.log('all promises complete');
            }, function(){
                console.log('error occurred with promises');
            });
```

I have comments in the parseTweet function and I see all of the tweets being parsed but not inside the Promise.all block - and the program never completes, keeps running until I kill it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, function "alchemyapi.sentiment" is async and you are calling a lot of times, exactly "tweets.statuses.length", and, at the end of your code you are calling function "res.send" so you call this function before "for loop" end, so, this is my approach to the solution (pseudocode):

1) Create a function that receive a tweet, create the tweet data (your logic + alchemyapi.sentiment). This function return a javascript promise (in my example I will use jquery defer to write less code, but you can use native promise):

```
function parseTweet(tweet) {
        $promise = $.defer();
        var tweetDataObject = {}; // this is not important, put your required data

        // call alchemyapi async
        alchemyapi.sentiment("text", ttext, {}, function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'OK' ) {
                // parse data and "return" valid object
                $promise.resolve(tweetDataObject);
            } else { // data is not valid, return null
                $promise.reject(null); // null, empty object, what you need
            }
        }); 

        return $promise;
    }
```

2) On your main method, do the for loop, call function parseTweet (that return something like promise) and wait for ALL promise:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i=0; i<tweets.statuses.length; i++) {
    promises.push(parseTweet(tweets.statuses[i]));

    $.when(promises).then(function() {
        // here, on "arguments" you have array of objects that parseTweet "return" when called resolve or reject

        console.log(arguments);
    });
}
```

I wrote the example using jquery defer, but it's easy with native promises (specially at this case that we have a lot number of promises to wait on $.when function).

Please, read carefully this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

### UPDATED: Example

I did an example on github. If you have doubts let me know, but I think that it's very clear
https://github.com/josemato/stackoverflow/tree/master/es-promise-all-no-order

Comment: Also Consider using '`http.get` (or for fine grained control `http.request`) instead of `client` since it is is deprecated.  Essentially you pass it an object with information about the web server you are connecting to, and a callback function for when the call is made (but not necessarily complete). Then you can use `response.on('end', ...`, which happens when it is done, to call the code suggested by @jose-mato

Comment: I had started to comment but realized it was easier to edit my post with the code changes I made. Still having issues. Thank you.

Comment: I wrote an example for you @user2255700 on my github account: https://github.com/josemato/stackoverflow/tree/master/es-promise-all-no-order

Comment: Jose, your example works fine and I understand what you did and how to apply it. I am still not able to use it for the problem I am working on. When I start with a hardcoded list of tweet data in an array, then use Promises to pass it to do the alchemyapi sentiment parsing it works great, just like in your example. But when I modify the code to use the Twitter API  (the client variable was just an instance of the Twitter module BTW) it never gets to the point where Promises.all triggers - it hangs at that point. Unsure why...

Comment: Jose - I found the issue, I needed to wrap the entire Twitter API call (client.get) inside a Promise - looks like its working now as it should. Thank you so much for patiently explaining and providing that helpful example - doubt I would have ever figured this out without your help!

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easy with vert.x: when the request event comes in, defer it to a worker module and let it do the long running processing.  Register a handler that processes the "all finished" event for display.

Maybe that process works for node.js as well: Make the long running alchemy calls a separate thread that registers an "all finished" event when it's done.  Ask the UI to register itself with the callback to render when it receives that event.